# Unity HDRP toggle Post-Processing Effects per script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post-processing

So, well as the title says i'm using the HighDefinitionRenderPipeline in Unity and i want to toggle a Post-Processing effect on/off using a script. But it seems to be harder as it looks.

So i know and am able to access the effect by their volume:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition;

public class PostProcessingTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Volume volume; // Volume referenced in the inspector

    void Start()
    {
        volume.profile.TryGet(out Bloom bloom); // Access the bloom effect

        bloom.intensity.value = 0.35f; // Some number for example
    }
}
```

There is a method to enable/disable for some effects like the ScreenSpaceReflections:

```
volume.profile.TryGet(out ScreenSpaceReflection reflections);

reflections.enabled.value = true; // In this case enables the reflections
```

But you cannot use the same method for the bloom for example.
There is a variable for the effects called "active":

```
bloom.active = true; // Should enable bloom
reflections.active = false; // Should disable reflections
```

It seems to do nothing, at least not what i want to achieve;

Some people used this method:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;

public class PostProcessingTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] PostProcessVolume volume; // Volume referenced in the inspector

    void Start()
    {
        volume.profile.TryGetSettings(out Bloom bloom); // Access the bloom effect

        bloom.enabled.value = true; // Enables Bloom
    }
}
```

But this did not work for me since I am using the HDRP Post-Processing and not the regular one.

I came up with the idea to just save the default bloom intensity and set it to 0 if it got disabled but this is a more difficult progress and i wanted to know if there is a better way.